# Send file with jquery and recive in PHP (No plugIn)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm trying to send a file using AJAX with the form but the PHP file seems to receive nothing, not only the files but also the form elements. In PHP if i try to get a value from the `$_POST` i get an `Undefined Index`.
I've tried:

```
    $("#animal-insert").click((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fd = $("#animal-form-input");
    var files = $("#file")[0].files[0];
    fd.append("file", files);

    $.ajax({
        url: "php_utility/ajax/admin-animal.php",
        type: "post",
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response === "allok") {
                showModalError("Registrato Correttamente", "modalsuccess");
            } else {
                showModalError("Non Registrato Correttamente", "modalerror");
            }
        },
    });
```

and the method you see in the code below. I'm restricted to do this without plugins.
I was also trying with the `$.post()` but if i understood correctly i have to use `$.ajax()` to add the `processData: false` to send files.

### HTML

```
 <form method="POST" action="" id="animal-form-insert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="span-1-of-2">
                                <label for="specie" class="label">Specie Animale:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="animal-input" id="specie" name="specie" required placeholder="Pavo cristatus">
                                <label for="an-name" class="label">Nome Comune:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="animal-input" id="an-name" name="an-name" required placeholder="pavone comune">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span-1-of-2">
                                <label for="biom" class="label">Bioma/Habitat:</label>
                                <select class="animal-input" name="biom" id="biom" required>
                                    <option value="Savana">Savana</option>
                                    <option value="Tundra">Tundra</option>
                                    <option value="Pianura">Pianura</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="zoo-zone" class="label">Zona Zoo:</label>
                                <select class="animal-input" name="zoo-zone" id="zoo-zone">
                                    <option value="A">A</option>
                                    <option value="B">B</option>
                                    <option value="C">C</option>
                                    <option value="F">F</option>
                                    <option value="PN">PN</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <label for="animal-photo" class="label">Foto Animale:</label>
                            <input type="file" id="animal-photo" name="animal-photo" accept=".jpg,.jpeg.png" required>

                            <label for="aniaml-desc" class="label">Descrizione:</label>
                            <textarea class="animal-input-desc" name="animal-desc" id="animal-desc" required></textarea>

                            <button type="submit" name="animal-insert" id="animal-insert" class="btn btn-block">Aggiungi</button>
                        </form>
```

### JS

```
    $("#animal-insert").click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = {
            specie: $("#specie").val(),
            anname: $("#an-name").val(),
            biom: $("#biom").val(),
            zoozone: $("#zoo-zone").val(),
            animaldesc: $("#animal-desc").val(),
            animalphoto: $("#animal-photo")[0].files[0],
            submit: "submit",
        };

        console.log(formData);

        $.ajax({
            url: "php_utility/ajax/admin-animal.php",
            type: "post",
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response === "allok") {
                    showModalError("Registrato Correttamente", "modalsuccess");
                } else {
                    showModalError("Non Registrato Correttamente", "modalerror");
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

### PHP

```
<?php

error_log($_POST['specie']);

if (isset($_POST['specie'])) {

    $animalspecie = $_POST['specie'];
    $animalName = $_POST['anname'];
    $animalBiom = $_POST['biom'];
    $animalZone = $_POST['zoozone'];
    $animalDesc = $_POST['animaldesc'];
    $animalPhoto = $_FILES['animalphoto'];
    $animalPhotoName = $animalPhoto['name'];
    $photoTmp = $animalPhoto['tmp_name'];
    $photoErr = $animalPhoto['error'];
    $photoType = $animalPhoto['type'];
    error_log("not here");
    $formats = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];

    require_once '../sql/utility.php';  //file with functions for db
    require_once '../checks.php'; //file with some type checks

    if (empty($animalspecie) || empty($animalName) || empty($animalBiom) || empty($animalZone) || empty($animalDesc) || empty($animalPhoto)) {
        echo "emptyinput";
        exit();
    }
    if (!preg_match('/[A-Z]+[a-z]+\s[a-z]+/', $animalspecie)) {

        echo "invalidspecie";
        exit();
    }

    if (!in_array($photoType, $formats)) {
        echo "invalidformat";
        exit();
    }
    if ($photoErr !== 0) {
        echo "fileerror";
        exit();
    }

    $tmpExtension = explode("/", $photoType);
    $photoExtension = end($tmpExtension);
    $photoNewName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $animalName) . preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $animalName) . "." . $photoExtension;
    $photoDestination = "//resurces/images/animals/" . $photoNewName;

    move_uploaded_file($photoTmp, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $photoDestination);

    $result = insertAnimal($conn, $animalspecie, $animalName, $animalBiom, $animalZone, $animalDesc);
    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `new FormData()` and append your form values and files to it, and then send it as 'multipart/form-data'  in the `data` (not `body`) param.

```js
$("#animal-insert").click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("specie", $("#specie").val())
        formData.append("anname", $("#an-name").val())
        formData.append("biom", $("#biom").val())
        formData.append("zoozone", $("#zoo-zone").val())
        formData.append("animaldesc", $("#animal-desc").val())
        formData.append("animalphoto", $("#animal-photo")[0].files[0])
        formData.append("submit", "submit")

        $.ajax({
            url: "php_utility/ajax/admin-animal.php",
            method: "post",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response === "allok") {
                    showModalError("Registrato Correttamente", "modalsuccess");
                } else {
                    showModalError("Non Registrato Correttamente", "modalerror");
                }
            },
        });
    });
```

In PHP Your files will be avaiable in `$_FILES` array, and the other data will be in `$_POST` array.

More on FormData: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData